# Submitting Catcha on an external form

Tags: php, forms, curl

I've been presented with a challenge which has had be stumped now for a few days. I am working on a project for which I need to submit a form on an external sever which also has a captcha.

I am capable of solving the captcha and getting the proper values... I use curl with POST form to get attempt to submit the complete form using the captcha I've managed to get.

However, when I run the script, I a returned message that the security code (captcha) was incorrect. I believe it might be because once use curl to post, the image has a different code?

Here is the code I am using:

```
# SAVE CAPTCHA
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}


function postform(){
grab_image('path to/site', 'captcha.jpg');
$image = 'captcha.jpg';
$client = new DeathByCaptcha_SocketClient("myusername", "mypassword");
if ($captcha = $client->decode($image, 10)) {
    $url = "path to url in form action";
    $data = array();
    $data['submit']='1';
    $data['name']='my name';
    $data['comments']='Success Posting This Form';
    $data['vercode']=$captcha['text'];
    $data['Send']='Send Email to Breeder';

    $post_str = '';

    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        $post_str .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&';
    }

    $post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, TRUE); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo $output;
    }
```

Again... after running this, I get that the captcha code is incorrect. Everything else seems to have worked fine and I'm able to solve the captcha. I guess my main difficulty lies in being able to make sure that the captcha code submitted is the same that is expected. Perhaps it refreshed? I'm not sure.

Any help on resolving this challenge will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I cannot see how this could be used for anything other than a HACK

Comment: Might seem like it.. but it's actually a list of our members on a remote sister website. Due to a programming error, we need to send them the access to their control panel through this form. We don't directly manage the other server and the system was built built by a hired developer who they no longer have access to. The management team are a dog adoption agency who built this website to help our shared members connect people with families... They are however zero percent tech savvy and barely know what a power button is. It's easier to go about it this way.

Comment: This is actual pretty intuitive.